# Android MediaController End Of song

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I have a play service that is playing audio in background task.  I am letting MediaController control the playback of the audio in a "player window" which handles the playback UI.

All works fine except then the song gets to the end.  The player does not "reset" as I would like it to.  I want the progress bar to return to 0 and the pause/play button to revert back to play.

I can get the progress bar to return to 0 with a call to mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);  How do I get the MediaController to reset the pause/play button back to show the play button?

Comment: Did you try to call `show(0)` again when the song gets to the end? Like `controller.show(0)`

Comment: Wow Thanks cylon!   That was it.  I always have the player showing so didn't think that show(0) would have an effect but it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that show(0) after the audio has ended, re-displays the UI correctly.  Thanks Cylon for the help!